# Capturing name of StackPanel from Drop event

Tags: wpf

Within WPF I have the following XAML code:

```
  <Page x:Class="com.MyCo.MyProj.Pages.Configuration.ManageLinkage.MasterLinkage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:com.MyCo.MyProj.Pages.Configuration.ManageLinkage"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="MasterLinkage">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Top" Background="Transparent">
        <TabItem Header="Import">
            <ListBox Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="lbxImportItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"  Background="Transparent"
                     PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="lbxImportItems_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="DBImport">
                    <Image Source="/Images/DBImport25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="Database" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="CSVImport">
                    <Image Source="/Images/CSVImport25px.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="CSV Import" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Canvas x:Name="cnvsLinkScreen" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" Drop="cnvsLinkScreen_Drop" DragOver="cnvsLinkScreen_DragOver" ></Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The code for capturing the event is here:

```
    private void cnvsLinkScreen_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas parent = (Canvas)sender;
        object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
        StackPanel objIn = (StackPanel)e.Data;
      ...
    }
```

The drag and drop work great, the event method created the image in the canvas.  However, I want to capture the Name="" from the StackPanels which are dropped.

I found the Name buried super deep in the "DragEventArgs e" object.  I was think that there should be a way to cast the object (or the object within that object) as a StackPanel to easily work with it.  The above code does not convert the StackPanel object( it's not at the root or the child object; I tried both) so it exceptions on "StackPanel objIn = (StackPanel)e.data;"

How do I either translate the incoming object to a StackPanel or how do I access the Name attribute from the Stackpanel?

Comment: Complete the XAML. In the provided code, the Canvas is not visible, so the layout of the elements is not possible to understand.
Also show where in XAML the link to the "cnvsLinkScreen_Drop" method is.

Comment: Just add a canvas to the layout.  Layout is irrelevant to the question, my question is around the data being passed to the event handler...  But, regardless, I added the rest of the XAML per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  I was close with the translation.  To translate / typecast the object to what you are working with I needed to use the following line:

```
StackPanel objIn = (StackPanel)(e.Data.GetData(typeof(StackPanel)));
```

Which is slightly different than above.